# How to find the matrix of correlations between multiple variables in R?

Tags: r, encoding, syntax

```
library(MASS)
library(ISLR)

auto = read.csv("auto.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = "?")
auto = auto[,-9]
cor(auto$mpg, auto$cylinders)
```

I am having a hard time getting the right result for the matrix of correlations between 8 independent variables in R. I know that cor() is the function to use but the syntax is just x and y. If there are a lot of independent variables in a regression model, how should I do it?

Comment: please provide the auto.csv- so we an reproduce your code

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the whole dataset in `cor()`.

```
data(mtcars)
cor(mtcars)
```

In your case, probably do this:

```
auto = read.csv("auto.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = "?")
auto = auto[,-9]
auto = as.data.frame(auto)
cor(auto)
```